# socket programming in linux: send()

Tags: linux, network-programming

I'm a beginner in socket programming in linux env.

the code is :

```
void proccess_server(int s)
{

    ssize_t size =0 ;
    char buffer[1024];
    for(;;)
    {
        printf("proccess:%d proccessing socket :%d\n",getpid(),s);
        size = recv(s,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);

        if(0 == size)
          return ;
        sprintf(buffer,"Response from server:%d,%d bytes altogether\n",getpid(),size);

        send(s,buffer,strlen(buffer)+1,0);
    }

}
```

and I don't understand why `len` param in `send()` add another byte `(strlen(buffer)+1)` in  `send(s,buffer,strlen(buffer)+1,0);`

please help me !

Comment: This code is all wrong, where did you find it ? It does not check for error conditions (size == -1), and it expect "buffer" to be null terminated without checking for it, so it has a security flaw.

Comment: er..It's a simple tutorial show the network programming api form my text book. and if I want to fix it ,should I fill buffer with \0 before receive data?

Comment: yes, and you should recv sizeof(buffer)-1 bytes at most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C language, compiler puts a \0 (NULL) character at the end of every string. So while you are using a string, computer can understand where that string ends. In Pascal language example, compiler puts a byte front of string to store length of string.

This must be the reason why there is +1 there.

Comment: I see,I understand there will be a \0 at the end of the string,as the question is ,+1 means the function strlen() return the length of a string not include \0?

Comment: Yes, that is right. If a string is "abc", strlen("abc") is 3, but in memory length is 4.